# Running rviz in the background using "docker exec -d"

Tags: docker, ros

I use ros1 in ubuntu18.04 which is as a docker container. I have already launched a container, and I want to run my `rviz` in the background. When I try to run it using the command`docker exec -d walker-container bash -c "rviz"`but there is no any windows prompt out, and checking with "docker logs " doesn't show anything. However, running `docker exec -d walker-container bash -c "gedit"` works fine.

I'd like to know how to successfully run rviz in the background using "docker exec -d." Can someone please provide guidance on this issue?

Thank you.

I expected this command to start the rviz process in the background within the specified Docker container so that I could use it for ROS operations.

Comment: A Docker container is a wrapper around a single process only.  If you want a second background process, usually the best way to get that is as the only process in a second container.  I'd suggest using `docker exec` sparingly, for debugging when required but not as the main way to interact with the process in a container.  Do you have any sort of source code, Dockerfiles, _etc._ that would make this a programming question, or are you just trying to run a prebuilt program?

Comment: Hello, my Docker setup is a basic Ubuntu 18.04 with ROS installed, and I don't have any Dockerfile. I'm looking to automate the launch of ROS. If the methods mentioned earlier are not feasible, are there any other ways to achieve automation? For instance, running `docker exec -it walker-container bash; roscore` directly in the terminal, and then launching roscore inside Docker. However, I understand that this approach is not workable.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just run it using:

```
rosrun rviz rviz
```

(Assuming you have it within the same workspace)

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant permission for the local user to connect to the X server. In the X Window System, the X server is responsible for managing graphical displays and user interfaces.
you can do it by:

```
xhost +local:
```

then run docker

```
docker run -itd -net=host container_name/id
```

then

```
docker exec -d walker-container bash -c "rviz"
```